# What does “Downtonised” mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

From [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/film/2017/feb/12/viceroys-house-review-soapy-account-of-indias-birth-agonies):

> Hugh Bonneville and Gillian Anderson play the Mountbattens in Gurinder Chadha cheekily Downtonised but watchable version of history

What does *Downtonised* mean?  [Google Web Search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22downtonised%22) gives a few other contexts, such as this one, also [from the Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/media/bbc/2016/nov/03/all):

> While the US TV view of the UK is all Downtonised nostalgia, British telly is obsessed with documenting the extremities of America.

And from the [Incorporated Council of Law Reporting](http://www.iclr.co.uk/weekly-notes-legal-news-from-iclr-11-september-2015/):

> It was almost as though the trial had never been won, and we’d been served a sanitised, Downtonised version instead.

I can't find a meaning in the usual sources.  What does it mean?

Comment: The only thing I can tell is that it's capitalized so it must be a proper noun.

Comment: It is probably meant to echo "bowdlerized".

Answer (score 2):

I believe it might be a reference to the British TV series 'Downton Abbey'.  As such it would be referring to the style of the show and it's handling of the events it portrayed.

Sadly I only saw the first series so can't definitively say if its a good or bad thing to be, though your quote from icrl.co.uk implies it's not that great.

Comment: I suppose that the followup question would be: what characterises Downton Abbey, but that question may be better asked on [Movies.SE]…